# jcrop cropping many images getting id of image which is being cropped

Tags: javascript, php, image, jcrop

I have a loop which generates panels containing images.

```
<div class="panel edited_picture"'>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h3 class="title-hero">
            Zdjęcie #{{$picture->id}}
        </h3>
        <div class="example-box-wrapper">
            <img picture_id='{{$picture->id}}  src="{{$picture->get_full_path()}}" class="jcrop-handler" alt="Example image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to read the image id which is being cropped. Preferably by reading the attribute value.

The below code doesn't work:

```
 $('.jcrop-handler').Jcrop({
    onChange: showCoords,
    onSelect: showCoords,
    onRelease: clearCoords
}, function() {
    jcrop_api = this;

});


    function showCoords(c) {

       id = $(this).attr('picture_id');
alert(id);
}
```

Comment: Explain "doesn't work"